# gitignore file rewritten on pull

Tags: git

Steps:

- have a file in the repo for basic configs
- checkout the repo
- put the file in .gitignore
- modified the file
- git status, still there, so i did an assume-unchanged
- no longer in git status
- did some development work and pulled someone else's code (pulled files have nothing to do with this file)
- somehow the file in .gitignore gets rewritten back to the initial contents!

Anyone knows why and how to get around this?

I do not want to delete the file in the remote nor local view. I just want to disconnect them. They're not in git status and not in git log so I have no idea why it gets reverted back.. Not using branch yet, just master stuff here.

Answer (score 1):

This is not something easily solved with git. `.gitignore` doesn't work on tracked files, only on untracked files.

So assume-unchanged is the only way to keep it out of git status, but this will cause problems when trying checkout other branches, or merge changes back in, because git normally doesn't overwrite uncommitted changes.

That it reverted the changes is not normal behaviour of git. So it would help enormously if you provided a transcript of you terminal session.

Comment: Thanks, what specific commands are you looking for the transcript for? git log? I did a git ls-files -v to make sure the file is in assume unchanged. It's working fine "h config.json"

Comment: I usually don't even know when it got reverted or which files have this behavior, until my script turns up with errors and I trace them to the config file. I'm using googlecode git